# Scala 2: Case class pattern matching to show error

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a case class like this:

```
case class AEMError(
  authError: Option[AEMAuthError] = None,
  unexpectedError: Option[AEMUnexpectedError] = None,
                   )
```

I want to do a pattern matching like this:

```
def throwErrorAndLogMessage(error:AEMError,message:String):Unit={
    error match {
      case authError: Some[AEMAuthError] => {???}
      case unexpectedError: Some[AEMUnexpectedError] => {???}
      case _ => {???}
    }
  }
```

and add multiple case classes for different types of error but I am totally spinning on the syntax for case match can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definition of `AEMError` you can't do reasonable pattern matching because it possible to have both error present.

You should change `AEMError` to

```
sealed trait AEMError

case class AEMErrorAuth(authError: AEMAuthError) extends AEMError

case class AEMErrorUnexpected(authError: AEMUnexpectedError) extends AEMError
```

And use it like this:

```
  err match {
    case AEMErrorAuth(authError) => {
      print(authError)
    }
    case AEMErrorUnexpected(unexpectedError) => {
      print(unexpectedError)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change the signature of `AEMError` like @talex mentioned, you can try something like:

```
  def throwErrorAndLogMessage(error: AEMError, message: String): Unit = {
    error match {
      case AEMError(Some(authError), Some(unexpectedError)) => ???
      case AEMError(Some(authError), None) => ???
      case AEMError(None, Some(unexpectedError)) => ???
      case _ => ???
    }
  }
```